# .net detect distributed transaction

Tags: .net, transactions, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

In my application I use the following pattern for calling the DB:

```
    //do a transaction 
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    OperationOnDb1();

    //when we open the connection to the “other db” in this call, the transaction would become distributed
    OperationOnDb2();

    //transaction is now distributed
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

The problem is that Operation1 and Operation2 90% of the time use the same db ... but there are cases (bugs) when they use two DBs. I want to get an exception if the transaction becomes distributed.

How can I detect if the transaction is promoted to a distributed transaction?

Thanks, Radu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also have a look at the following event

[TransactionManager.DistributedTransactionStarted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionmanager.distributedtransactionstarted.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `DistributedTransactionPermissionAttribute`. It's using the `DistributedTransactionPermission` class wich is the permission that is demanded by System.Transactions when management of a transaction is escalated to MSDTC (from doc).

You could apply it to your piece of code. A security exception should be raised on escalation.

Comment: +1 For your tip. Now I have got an exception whenever my code crosses the line. Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like modern .NET runtime ignores CAS attributes.

Comment: @yallie - absolutely

Answer (score 3):

While your `TransactionScope` is ongoing, you may test:

```cs
Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier != Guid.Empty
```

[`DistributedIdentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactioninformation.distributedidentifier?view=netframework-4.7) is `Empty` if the transaction is not yet promoted to distributed. From its documentation, remarks section:

> If the transaction is escalated to a two-phase commit transaction, this property returns its unique identifier. If the transaction is not escalated, the value is `Empty`.