# Detect whether a query is in a distributed transaction

Tags: sql-server, distributed-transactions

I need a reliable way to determine, from within a SQL Server query, whether the query is running inside a distributed transaction.<sup>1</sup>  It doesn't matter whether the distributed transaction was created externally or with a `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION` statement — either way, I need to know about it.

I don't see a specific [SQL Server function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/system-functions-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/database-engine-stored-procedures-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) claiming to provide this information.  There are some [dynamic-management views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/transaction-related-dynamic-management-views-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) whose documentation claims will provide this information, but the information is unreliable.  For example, [`sys.dm_tran_session_transactions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-session-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has the column `is_local`:

> 1 = Local transaction.
>
> 0 = Distributed transaction or an enlisted bound session transaction.

So, test it, making use of `SAVE TRANSACTION`, which [is unsupported in a distributed transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) and will cause an error.<sup>2</sup>

This query is not in a distributed transaction and works as expected, selecting a value of 1 for `is_local`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT s.is_local
FROM   sys.dm_tran_session_transactions s

SAVE TRANSACTION Error

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

But, if we replace `BEGIN TRANSACTION` with `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION`, `is_local` is still 1, but we get the error "Cannot use SAVE TRANSACTION within a distributed transaction."  So, we cannot rely on the `is_local` value.

How about [`sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-active-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?  Its `transaction_type` column is described:

> Type of transaction.
>
> 1 = Read/write transaction
>
> 2 = Read-only transaction
>
> 3 = System transaction
>
> 4 = Distributed transaction

We'll also need a way to identify the current transaction, which [`sys.dm_tran_current_transaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-current-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) provides.  So, let's test again:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT a.transaction_type
FROM   sys.dm_tran_current_transaction c
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions a ON c.transaction_id = a.transaction_id

SAVE TRANSACTION Error

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

For this non-distributed transaction, we get a value of 1, though 2 might also be possible.  But, replace `BEGIN TRANSACTION` with `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION` again, and we get the same value for `transaction_type`, but this time with the error from `SAVE TRANSACTION`.  So, we cannot rely on `transaction_type` either.

Just to ensure that the issue isn't actual enlistment in the distributed transaction, I have also tried using [`TransactionScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) from C# code.

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Transactions;
using IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel;

namespace TransactionTroubleshooting
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string ConnectionString = "Server=.;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        // Use C# 7.1 or later.
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                await RunOuterTransaction();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var current = e;
                while (current != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(current.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(current.StackTrace);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    current = current.InnerException;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press a key...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }   
        }

        private static async Task RunOuterTransaction()
        {
            using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted},
                TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = @"
SELECT a.transaction_type
FROM   sys.dm_tran_current_transaction c
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions a ON c.transaction_id = a.transaction_id
";
                    using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Outer transaction_type is {0}", reader["transaction_type"]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                await RunInnerTransaction();
                transaction.Complete();
            }
        }

        private static async Task RunInnerTransaction()
        {
            // We need Required, not RequiresNew, to get the distributed transaction.
            using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted },
                TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = @"
SELECT a.transaction_type
FROM   sys.dm_tran_current_transaction c
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions a ON c.transaction_id = a.transaction_id

-- Because this query is in a distributed transaction, if you want to throw, uncomment:
-- SAVE TRANSACTION Error
";

                    using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Inner transaction_type is {0}", reader["transaction_type"]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                transaction.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:
[image: Output from C# code]

Uncommenting `SAVE TRANSACTION` does the same thing with an added exception, as expected, indicating a distributed transaction.  `is_local` from earlier can be tested similarly.  Once again, neither `is_local` nor `transaction_type` reliably indicates a distributed transaction.

I have been unable to find another documented way to try detecting a distributed transaction within SQL.  Is it possible?  If so, how?

¹ <sub>This question is superficially related to [.net detect distributed transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274887/net-detect-distributed-transaction), but I need the detection from SQL rather than .NET.</sub>

² <sub>I need to detect the distributed transaction without causing an error, so I can't just put `SAVE TRANSACTION` in my query and wait for the error.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is to check a different field on the `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions` view.  [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-active-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) describes column `transaction_uow`:

> Transaction unit of work (UOW) identifier for distributed transactions. MS DTC uses the UOW identifier to work with the distributed transaction.

For every case I have found, when we are in a distributed transaction, `transaction_uow` is non-null; otherwise, `transaction_uow` is null.  The following SQL demonstrates:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT IIF(a.transaction_uow IS NULL, N'Not Distributed', N'Distributed') AS [Distributed?]
FROM   sys.dm_tran_current_transaction c
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions a ON c.transaction_id = a.transaction_id

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION

SELECT IIF(a.transaction_uow IS NULL, N'Not Distributed', N'Distributed') AS [Distributed?]
FROM   sys.dm_tran_current_transaction c
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions a ON c.transaction_id = a.transaction_id

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Results:

[image: Results from distributed-query check]

Behavior is the same when modifying the C# code in the question to test for the distributed transaction.